# How do I get the range address of items in my array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub sel_to_array()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i

    Sheets("Ps").Activate
    Sheets("Ps").Range("C6").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    'arr = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Value
    arr = Selection

    For Each i In arr
        MsgBox i

        If Round(i, 0) = Round(proj_cbox.Value, 0) Then
            GoTo 1:
        End If

        Next i

End Sub
```

Here is what it does: when it finds the equal match, I want to know what its cell location is, for example `A3` or `A13`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub sel_to_array()

    Dim arr As Range, rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Sheets("Ps").Activate
    lastRow = Sheets("Ps").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If lastRow <= 5 Then Exit Sub

    Set rng = Range("C6:C" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
        If Round(cell.Value, 0) = Round(proj_cbox.Value, 0) Then
            MsgBox cell.Address
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are bouncing the range to an array. If that is not really needed you could try this:

```
Sub sel_to_address()
  Dim MyRange As Range
  For Each MyRange In Range(Sheets("Ps").Range("C6"), Sheets("Ps").Range("C6").End(xlDown))
    MsgBox MyRange.Value
    If Round(MyRange.Value, 0) = Round(proj_cbox.Value, 0) Then
      MsgBox MyRange.Address
    End If
  Next MyRange
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a lot of `MsgBox`es ... :)

Comment: @BrandonR.Gates yes, yes it is (^:

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MsgBox i.Address
```

or you could do this

```
Set arr = Selection 'set here forces arr to a range object

If Round(i, 0) = Round(proj_cbox.Value, 0) Then
    With i.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = 36 'Light Yellow
    End With
Else
    i.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If
```

which will shade all cells with light yellow that match the value, and clear shading from all cells that don't.

Comment: In spite of possible appearance, `i` takes on the type of `Double` in the OP's code, so you can't use range properties on it.

Comment: Good catch.  Changing `arr = Selection` to `Set arr = Selection` fixed it.